# How to make null/undefined safe string comparision in angular markup?

Tags: angular, production-environment

So I had following condition:

```
<span *ngIf="!someItem?.description==''">
```

Condition: If someItem is defined and description isn’t an empty string. In general, we can say not equal to some X.

This works in a dev environment, when `someItem` is, and is not set, as well as when the description is and is not empty. However in a production build, I get the following error:

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and '""
```

How should I write such conditions to keep it nullsafe and valid on production builds?

Comment: try using brackets <span *ngIf="! (someItem?.description=='') ">

Comment: I did try that in fact as a hotfix attempt, but it works even worst throwing an runtime exception on dev that _co.someItem is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `!` operator has precedence over `==` so this is essentially `(!someItem?.description) == ''` which would compare a boolean to a string which is not allowed.

You probably want to use `someItem?.description != ''`. This will work properly even if `someItem` is undefined as it will compare `undefined != ''` which *is* allowed. However, this may not do what you want since `undefined != ''`.

Ultimately you may want to use `*ngIf="!someItem?.description"` which will work if `someItem` is undefined, does not have the `description` property, or `description` is any falsey value including an empty string.

Comment: Precedence would explain why AOT compiler is complaining so much and yes, doing `!someItem?.description` would work in that case, but what about general case of comparision to non empty string?

Comment: Should it be always if `someItem?.description && someItem!='X'` or  `!(someItem=='')`??

Comment: String comparision to empty string is a special case because as you mentioned empty string can be evaluated to false just by that. What would be general rule for string comparision to X where X is not an empty string

Comment: There is not a general case, but if you're comparing to a specific string then `someItem?.description == 'specific string'` would do it